# insert comma into this array so as to call each element individually

Tags: python

I have the following array to which I am trying to insert a comma between the numbers so that I can call each element individually, ie `a[0]=-4.5e-2, a[1]=7.8e-3` etc

```
a = np.array(['-4.5e-2 7.8e-3 1e-2'])
```

**Output**

```
array([['-4.5e-2 7.8e-3 1e-2'],
       dtype='<U19')
```

**Desired output**

```
array([-4.5e-2, 7.8e-3, 1e-2])
```

Comment: Have you tried a=np.array(['-4.5e-2 7.8e-3 1e-2'.replace(" ",",")])

Comment: yes, doesnt work. Cannot retrieve the individual elements. I think the key is to remove '<U19'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert into `dtype` `float64`,

```
In [1]: np.array(['-4.5e-2 7.8e-3 1e-2'.split()]).astype('float64')
Out[1]: array([[-0.045 ,  0.0078,  0.01  ]])
```

Values are:

```
In [2]: -4.5e-2
Out[2]: -0.045

In [3]: 7.8e-3
Out[3]: 0.0078

In [4]: 1e-2
Out[4]: 0.01
```

If you want to represent it exact the same way you need to keep it as a Unicode string or string. Like this,

```
In [5]: np.array(['-4.5e-2 7.8e-3 1e-2'.split()])
Out[5]: array([['-4.5e-2', '7.8e-3', '1e-2']], dtype='<U7')
```

If the array has more values you can do this,

```
In [1]: value = np.array([['1.28353e-02 3.24985e-02 6.12448e-02'], ['3.62696e-01 4.77613e-01 5.70936e-01 ']], dtype=object)
    
In [2]: np.array([i[0].split() for i in value]).astype('float64')
Out[2]: 
array([[-0.045 ,  0.0078,  0.01  ],
       [-0.045 ,  0.0078,  0.01  ]])
```

Comment: this works fine for array of shape (1,). How would I do it for array of shape (n,)?

Comment: My value is of the form array([['1.28353e-02  3.24985e-02  6.12448e-02''],
       ['3.62696e-01  4.77613e-01  5.70936e-01 ']],
      dtype=object)

Comment: @user9106985 Updated accordingly.